# Ограничение области действия глобального фильтра

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Вознилка следующая проблема, есть rest api с кучей контроллеров и есть глобальный фильтр действий. Необходимо, что фильтр применялся для всех методов контроллеров кроме пары специфичных. Каким образом можно ограничить область действия фильтра? Вариант с указанием атрибута фильтра для каждого контроллера или методов контроллера не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в самом фильтре сделать проверку на аттрибут. Если указан определённый отключающий атрибут `[FilterXDisabled]` на действие контроллера которое вызвано, то фильтр дальше не отрабатывает и делает return.

Атрибут надо самим создать будет.

Comment: А как глобальный фильтр связан с вызываемым методом?

Comment: @QuaternioNoir В фильтре можно узнать какой метод (действие) какого контроллера вызывается.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName` и `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName` Имя действия и контроллера. Далее через reflection узнать атрибуты.

Comment: Во спасибо)) тоже допер)

Comment: @QuaternioNoir вот тут много методов для рефлексии действия - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor(v=vs.118).aspx